# Remove marker border/line in scatterplot plotly R

Tags: r, plotly, scatter-plot, markers

This is my code:

```
BD_mapinc <- plot_ly(BD_tab, x=~East, y=~North, type='scatter', mode='markers',
                      text= ~paste("BD incr:", BD_tab$BD_incr, "No.:", Label),
                      size= ~BD_tab$BD_incr,
                      marker=list(color = ~BD_tab$BD_incr,
                                  colorbar=list(title='BD increment [%]'),
                                  colorscale='PuOr')
                      ) %>%
      layout(plot_bgcolor='#e5ecf6', 
             xaxis = list( 
               zerolinecolor = '#ffff', 
               zerolinewidth = 2, 
               gridcolor = 'ffff'), 
             yaxis = list( 
               zerolinecolor = '#ffff', 
               zerolinewidth = 2, 
               gridcolor = 'ffff'))
)
      
BD_mapinc
```

Ever since I found out how to add a title to the colorscale with the marker option, I also have unwanted marker borders.
Can someone help me? How can I remove them?
[What the plot currently looks like](https://i.stack.imgur.com/XTzsA.jpg)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can move some of your arguments into the marker function and set line width to zero to remove the lines around the markers:

```
BD_mapinc <- plot_ly(BD_tab, x=~East, y=~North, type='scatter', mode='markers',
                     text= ~paste("BD incr:", BD_tab$BD_incr, "No.:", Label),
                     marker=list(color = ~BD_tab$BD_incr,
                                 colorbar=list(title='BD increment [%]'),
                                 colorscale='PuOr',
                                 size= ~BD_tab$BD_incr,
                                 line=list(width=0)))%>%
  layout(plot_bgcolor='#e5ecf6', 
         xaxis = list( 
           zerolinecolor = '#ffff', 
           zerolinewidth = 2, 
           gridcolor = 'ffff'), 
         yaxis = list( 
           zerolinecolor = '#ffff', 
           zerolinewidth = 2, 
           gridcolor = 'ffff'))
```

Comment: thanks for your swift help! when I used exactly your code, the marker sizes were suddenly very big. So I pasted the size attribute back to the 'main body' (after text=~....) and now it looks just like I want to :)